# Data Studio custom Number Format

Tags: number-formatting, looker-studio

How can I set thousand separators in Google Data studio. Instead of **203,206,502** I want to show **20,32,06,502**. Kindly help

Comment: **Needs Details**: Share a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report [**TO-DO**] that reproduces a specific issue, using sample data, showing 1) Input values [DONE but more examples, ~9 would be better], 2) Expected output [DONE] 3) An issue / attempt at solving [**TO-DO**]. Without a specific use case ([Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) it would be difficult to visualise and pinpoint a suggestion as the issue could be the data, connector, chart or [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/12182485)

Answer (score 0):

Set number to currency. in my case peso PHP[image]